# When dividing $15$ objects into $3$ groups of $5$, what's the probability that object $x$ and $y$ will both be in the same group?

Tags: probability

I know that $P(A)$ where $A$ is the event that they're in the same group = $3 * P(B)$ where $B$ is the event that they're in any group.

The sample space is the multinomial: $M(15:5,5,5)$.  I just need to find the cardinality of $|B| = |X \cap Y|$ where $X$ and $Y$ are the events that $x$ and $y$ are in group $1$, respectfully.

If I was to make a tuple by concatenating each tuple representing its own group: $(a_1, ..., a_5, b_1, ..., b_5, c_1, ..., c_5)$, I see that this would be equivalent to finding the ways that $x$ and $y$ could be placed into this tuple (treating the other elements as essentially blank spaces) which would be $\frac{15!}{13!} = 15 * 14$ different ways.

But from here I'm stuck because I can't figure a way to remove the triple counting.

Comment: why not merely P(y in col z when x in col z ) which is = 1/3 as you did at the beginning ?

Comment: What do you mean by "P(y in ...) which is 1/3" ?

Comment: why not merely the probability that y in the column first chosen for x, which is = 1/3 as you did at the beginning ?

Comment: What are you referring to when you use the word column?

Comment: group ! but I was wrong ; Greg provides the good answer

Comment: there is $\binom{2}{3}+3$ eventual places, places that hold em both are 3, so  3 divided by $\binom{2}{3}+3$ is the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is not $\frac13$. (Note that the argument giving $\frac13$ would also work when dividing $3$ objects into $3$ groups of $1$—but it's not very likely for $x$ and $y$ to end up in the same group then...!)

No matter what happens, $x$ ends up in some group. There are $14$ places that $y$ could end up, and $4$ of them are in the same group as $x$. Therefore the probability that $x$ and $y$ are in the same group is $\frac4{14}=\frac27$.

Comment: yes it's the good answer because the amount by group ( 5 ) is fixe